# What does it mean for an object to be "tied" to an Activity/Context in Android?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-activity

I am specifically asking about this paragraph in the Android documentation:

> If the object you pass is for some reason tied to the
>   Activity/Context, you will leak all the views and resources of the
>   activity.

You can find this paragraph on the page about [Faster Screen Orientation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html) changes.

I assume they mean objects that keep a reference to the Activity/Context. In my Activity, I am returning a HashMap in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance, so I assume I am fine, since none of the objects in that HashMap contain references to the Activity/Context. But I want to make sure; I am still learning about how leaks happen in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick Dubroy has shown a video tutorial [doing showing something similar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=_CruQY55HOk#t=1502s). Then he proceeds to debug that leak. I guess you can follow the same procedure to confirm if your code is really leaky or not.

You are right, if the objects keep a reference to the Activity or Context, it won't allow the GC to collect those unused Activities, thus create a huge leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this and with the caveat that i may not even know as much as you do so far I keep seeing a `WeakRef` type used but then again I do not see people checking for nulls so from what I can gather on it if the user flips the phone around the system can if it gets tight just dump a process ~ then from what I see so far as I am learning is that as we know already System.gc is not exactly originally concept-ed to run on hand-held devices thus pointers kept in some kind of system table to translate between source code and what is actually going on in hardware ^can^ result in pointers being new'ed on re-entry thus when that happens it is not like careful coding and testing to not be keeping refs in a data-structure that does not get "heap-walked" once in awhile.

For sure avoid statics unless there is a reason and just a few days ago i ended up writing something as a `new Object(){ public methodNamedInAnInterface(){ /* stuff goes here  */ }}` but then after I thought about it that is a "best-effort" and we cannot program from code we write os issues that should be done in vendor's code shop where access to how it actually runs should be a normal and expected constraint

I use statics in my own code but then I am on an isolated local doing prototyping [ in other words I can re-start to dump stray pointers ]

I am shifting to a programming mental model where this code runs on a handheld, not a 10,000 requests a second constraint